# Language compatiblity issue in choregraphe

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

Current Project running in pepper supports both German and English language. When I try to run one new Project which supports only English language using Choregraphe. It doesn't work and gives me the below error message.

I change the robot language to English by accessing web-page of robot IP. But it still doesn't work.  I also added to German language to the new Project. But the Problem remains same.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
[ERROR] ALAutomaticAnnotation :setCurrentLanguage:0 Cannot annotate the language: German
[ERROR] behavior.translator :load:0 Fail to load translation for '/home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/.lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior' lang 'de_DE'
[ERROR] audio.alspeechrecognition :xTryTriggerSignsAndFeedback:0 Didn't trigger ExpressiveBit EndSpeechRecognitionEars: Cannot find service 'ALSignsAndFeedback' in index
```

What and how the necessary changes Need to be done in order to run new Project perfectly?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you start a new project or copy/paste from another one ? Try editing project option "File/project properties" and uncheck german in "supported language" list.

Comment: That works fine!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If your robot supports two languages then for each application you must add German as supported language. Maybe later you wish to install the app on another robot which support Japanese. Then you must have English, German and Japanese as supported languages.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, make sure the language support is enabled in project properties.

[image]